# Why do so many people put an accent on "râté"?

Tags: orthographe

I know that the correct form is "raté" but I see a lot of people writing "râté".
Is there an explanation for that?

Answer (score 9):

Likely because there are more similar words using a circumflex:

- bâté
- gâté
- hâté
- pâté
- tâté

than not:

- daté
- maté

The eye, more accustomed to see a circumflex accent in four-letter words ending in "-ate" affects the writing of the word "raté".

The influence of the spelling of one word to another is a common cause of mistakes. For example, *barrique* sometimes lead people to write *baril* with two R's, *barril*. The word *artichaut* (artichoke) is often written *artichaud* by the influence of *chaud* (hot).

Note that a circumflex accent changes the pronunciation of the A in francophone Belgium and Switzerland but doesn't make a strong difference or any difference at all in many parts of France except eastern regions.

See this [Mathieu Avanzi's page](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2019/04/14/qui-sont-ces-francophones-qui-prononcent-laccent-circonflexe/)

[image]

I guess people living in regions where there is no distinction are more likely to miswrite *raté*.

Comment: Do you find people also mispronounce it?

Comment: @LukeSawczak The  circumflex accent is not an indication of the pronunciation but of a lost s before the t; this s is found in the etymology.

Comment: @LPH This lost S definitely influenced the pronunciation, and still does it depending on the region. In that case it is pronounced [ɑ] vs [a]. See http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3697

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't think so.

Comment: @jlliagre I see, but nevertheless, there is no written rule, at least in modern grammars, that would say that there has to be a particular pronunciation because of that accent.

Comment: @LPH However universal it is or not, in this particular paradigm, bâté, gâté, hâté, pâté, tâté are all pronounced with [ɑ], whereas daté, maté, and raté are all pronounced with [a], at least according to Wiktionary (too many links to bother copying and pasting but compare [gâter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A2ter#Verbe) and [rater](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rater#Verbe)).

Comment: @LukeSawczak It's apparent that a rule (implicit at least) was [ɑ] for "â" and [a] for "a" but it has not been made evident to me as there was no difference in pronunciation in the regions where I attended school, nor rules about that in the basic grammars I used, although the explanation relative to the disappearance of the s was often made ; the pronunciation part, somehow was omitted.

Comment: @LPH There is not always a need for a rule, especially for such a linguistic feature that doesn't even concern all of the native speakers. But traditional pronunciations where the distinction between [ɑ] & [a] still exists makes it quite clear that "â" is only every used to indicate [ɑ] sounds, while "a", usually [a], varies (e.g. words in -ation have tended to evolve from [ɑsjɔ̃] to [asjɔ̃] in the last 50-70 years; "elle a" → [ɛlɑ], un tas → [œ̃tɑ]; in Quebec: la lettre A [ɑ], but commonly [a] if spelling a word out loud, even sometimes "[a] accent circonflexe").

Comment: @LPH Also, I know LBU has a comment about the two A sounds of the French language, but steers away from it almost immediately because: 1) it doesn't concern all native speakers, and some areas of the Francophonie have only one sound; 2) the distinction where it still exists is not always done the same way (Belgium uses 2 lengths instead of distinct sounds, for example); 3) even where the distinction exists, local areas may disagree on which words uses which A. As an example I know of first hand for point 3, the eastern part of Quebec says [kʁɑb] for "crabe", while the western part says [kʁab].

Comment: Another spelling vs. pronunciation curiosity (a bit beside the subject, since none of the examples use "â", but an interesting oddity as far as I'm concerned, and one that shows that analysis of unaccented A's is not always straightforward): "a" [ɑ] – "à" [a], but "la" [la] – "là" [lɑ]

Comment: Pour l'influence de «chaud» sur l'orthographe d'artichaut, j'ai comme un doute à la lumière du [*Dictionnaire de Trévoux,* 1771](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dictionnaire_de_Tr%C3%A9voux,_1771,_I.djvu/560): “ARTICHAUD, ou ARTICHAUT : on écrivoit autrefois Artichault. s. m. L’Académie a décidé pour artichaut, & au plur. artichauds.” Peut-être aussi en partie un fonds orthographique traditionnel qui a réussi à conserver la tête hors de l'eau depuis sa mise au rancart.

Comment: @Pasunclue Je doute qu'une orthographe aussi ancienne puisse influencer l'écriture de contemporains, en particulier celle d'enfants qui ont peu de chance d'avoir été en contact avec des écrits du XVIIIe ou du début du XIXe siècle où cette terminaison était encore attestée et admise.

Comment: De vieux livres de recettes, réécrits et recopiés de génération en génération, des vendeurs qui écrivent à la main. Les possibilités de persistence sont nombreuses et parfois inattendues. On peut douter, certes. Il est sain de mettre en doute. Mais je me permets aussi de douter de l'influence de chaud.

Comment: @Pasunclue Il faut douter de tout, tu as raison !